# Sketch up Modelling dynamically coloring the sides

Tags: c#, html, image-processing, sketchup, 3d-modelling

I have an advanced sketch up model of a new building project that has 21 floors and 4 side. Each side contains windows only. [image]

As you see I have colored one of four towers one side. Can I make it dynamically to show that that part of the project is available to be sold.

On the other hand if it is not possible to make it with Sketch Up or 3D max programs or etc. Assume that I have the final image without colors on it, can I color it using HTML5 or c# coding-image processing or mapping with dream works html tools like fireworks.

Thanks

Comment: Sketchup SDK (which is capable of reading and writing model files, so it could be what you want) is more C than C#, however there are some (unofficial I guess) .net tentatives. Have you looked at: https://github.com/moethu/SketchUpNET

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Could not solve it. @Pibben if u find a solution please welcome here.